# Sound reverberation in a completely flat environnement

Tags: acoustics

I don't know much about physics but I have a question.
Let's say you were lost in a completely flat desert, with seemingly nothing else surrounding it, and you screamed at the top of your lungs: would you be able to hear any echo/reverberation ?

Comment: What do you think? What's your reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

In the way you state it there would be no reverberation or echo since the (assumed/speculated) geometry (since you don't provide enough information) will not provide any reflections towards you.

Keep in mind though that another listener will "hear" (whether this will be sensed or not is another story though) some kind of "reverberation" (at least the direct sound and a reflection from the desert ground).